# TypeError: Cannot read property 'postId' of undefined (this.props.params no longer accessible )

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

OS: Windows 10 Pro
React-router: 4.1.1
React: 15.5.4

So, I'm migrating from react-router v2 to v4 and am experiencing an issue with the above mentioned param, in that is missing.

The error occurs when the route for `view/:postId (/view/0)` is matched, but the rendered component does not detect any existence of `this.props.params.postId`.

What is the issue here?

My routing component (Main.js) is as follows:

```html
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>
          <Link to="/">Flamingo City</Link>
        </h1>
        <Switch>
          <Route path={`${this.props.match.url}`} exact render={() => (
            <PhotoGrid {...this.props.children} {...this.props} />
            )} />
          <Route path={`${this.props.match.url}view/:postId`} render={() => (
            <Single {...this.props.children} {...this.props} />
            )} />
          <Route path={`${this.props.match.url}login`} component={LoginUser} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

And my rendered component (Single.js) is as follows:

```html
class Single extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  
  render() {
    const postId = this.props.params.postId;
    const { data, i, key } = this.props;
    
    if (data.loading) {
      return <p>Loading ...</p>;
    }
    if (data.error) {
      return <p>{data.error.message}</p>;
    }  
    return (
      <div className="single-photo">
        <Photo key={key} postIndexID={postId} post={data.allPostses[postId]} postId={data.allPostses[postId].id} {...this.props} />
        <Comments key={key} post={data.allPostses[postId]} postId={data.allPostses[postId].id} postIndexID={postId} {...this.props}  />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Single;
```

Update:

It appears that params is now accessed by doing this.props.match.params, but upon inspection in devTools the object is empty. What is the issue here?

Comment: Are you rendering server side?

Comment: @DerekLawrence No. Client side.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to refactor the route as follows:

```html
          <Route path={`${this.props.match.url}view/:postId`} render={(props) => (
            <Single {...this.props} {...props} />
            )} />
```